# EntityFramwork 6 - ID not set when calling SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6

I got a little Problem with my EntityFramework. 
My Setup is as follows :
I am using Code-First Migrations and this is the Database structure :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;

namespace myProject.DataObjects
{
    public class ListRelations : EntityData
    {
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public bool read { get; set; }
        public bool write { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now inherting from EnitityData should add the ID field and all the meta data stuff, right ?
When I try to populate the database like so :

```
            var relations = new ListRelations();
            relations.userID = currentUser;
            relations.read = true;
            relations.write = true;
            relations.listID = current.Id;
            context.ListRelationsSet.Add(relations);
            try {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                validationError.PropertyName,
                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am getting errors, saying the ID field is needed to be populated.
But, shouldnt the database do this for me ? 
I am a bit confused, 
welcoming any help!

Comment: What is in `EnitityData`?

Comment: This : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587298.aspx

Comment: [`EntityData.Id`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587151.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.EntityData.Id) type is `string`, the database cannot populate it for you (it's not identity if you understand what I mean)

Comment: @IvanStoev i see, but isnt that stupid? The EntityData is meant to be used this way, no?

Comment: To be honest, sounds stupid :) But I've never used and have no idea what's the benefit of using `EntityData` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev well tbh i just thought it was a simple "shortcut" to not need the id field and created at etc. to every class but yeah

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry for reviving this but I cant just get my head around this. If I use a string as Key, i cannot get it populated automatically. However, Microsoft docs say this : Typically, when starting from an Entity Framework Code-First model in your .NET Backend, you would use string ids. [Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/22/tables-with-integer-keys-and-the-net-backend/). So now i am confused.... Do I use strings as keys ? And if yes, how can the db populate it?

Comment: This actually has been asked here [Best practice for Ids Entity framework code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933170/best-practice-for-ids-entity-framework-code-first). I personally never used `string` PK in my practice.

Comment: @IvanStoev but if i try to implement ITableData it needs to be a string... and if it is a string it cant be populated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public class ListRelations : EntityData
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity),
     Column(TypeName = "varchar"),
     MaxLength(20),
     Key]
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public bool read { get; set; }
    public bool write { get; set; }
}
```

It depends on your database provider, but for instance T-Sql has a procedure called `newsequentialid()` to help populate these kind of columns.

Sample use in migration could be

```
 Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"),
```

Comment: Digging a little deeper, it is said that setting default value constraints via annotations will get supported in EF 7. Until then it looks as though we must modify the migration manually https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first